# Using the index of a for loop to name new objects inside the loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I want to run a for loop with index `i` so that I can define (inside each loop) an `ndarray` with name `A_i`. More concretely, I want it to look something like

```
for i in range(numer):
    A_i = M
```

where `M` is some `ndarray` that was defined in a previous step. The way I'm looking for is probably something reminiscent of the `.format()` method that works for strings.

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa I tried it out both with lists and dictionaries, but it makes more sense (for the code i'm writing) to have these objects as, say, `A_i`, rather than, say, `A[i]`.

Comment: Yes there is a method given below to create based on globals or the one based on exec.Both of them should be fine?

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa yeah, but people there comment that that's not recommended. But if it's the only way, it'd do I guess

Comment: Also see [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: Your other question about joining many arrays with names like 'A_1','A_2' illustrates the problem with creating objects with 'dynamic' names.  Not only is it a pain to create them, it is also a pain to use them.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, message received then! haha I guess I won't be using A_i. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can create all objects using globals() or locals() methods, depending if you want your objects to have global or local scope.

```
for i in range(10):
    globals()[f'A_{i}'] = M

for i in range(10):
    locals()[f'A_{i}'] = M
```

Still, this isn't a highly recommended practice.

Comment: It's not only not recommended, much less "highly", the documentation for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) explicitly notes: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified".

Comment: I agree. In fact, I point out in my answer that it’s a non-recommended practice. However, I consider appropriate to theorize about it and expose the different possibilities that language offers.

Comment: Guess we disagree. I don't think showing folks how *not* to do things is very helpful or enlightening—there's plenty of that kind of stuff this site already without your "contribution". There's also the fact that dynamically creating variables, by any means, is a poor programming practice unto itself (which you would know if you'd read any of the linked questions and articles about why that's the case).